# archivo properties esta en carpeta principal de proyecto pero la quiero en la carpeta del .jar

Tags: java, netbeans, archivo-de-propiedades

Agregué un archivo *properties* a mi proyecto, este archivo se guarda en la carpeta principal del proyecto mientras que el jar se guarda en la carpeta dist. Cada vez que quiero probar el jar tengo que mover el archivo properties a su carpeta y cada que compilo la solución se borra y tengo que hacerlo otra vez.

> ¿Existe una forma de que cada vez que se compile el archivo properties
>   también se guarde en la carpeta del jar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes colocar el archivo `.properties` dentro del paquete `default` del proyecto, de esa manera el archivo formará parte de tus fuentes y estará disponible dentro del jar.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta saludos